# How to turn off rails 3.1 verbosity in test unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am trying to run rails tests in the old fashion i.e. dots as output but think I am missing something. I cant find where to turn off the verbosity mode and every time I run a rake task I get a list of test descriptions which at first look nice but end up being quite boring and not very helpful.

How can I turn off rails test unit verbosity mode and get back to old ....F....E..... ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `turn` gem from your `Gemfile`.